# How to Modify a Widgets UL and/or LI Classes

Tags: theme-development, widgets, core, twitter-bootstrap

Im attempting to use twitter **UL** styles on a custom menu widget.

For example, in BootStrap they have a [Nav List Style](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs) for UL's

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="nav-header">List header</li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Which I am trying to integrate with a Custom Menu...

```
<div class="menu-footer_left-container">
    <ul id="menu-footer_left" class="menu"><!-- I need to add "nav nav-list" here! -->
        <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-100"><a href="http://mysite.dev">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://mysite.dev/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'd **like** to be able to do is add the classes to the UL **and** LI's, but I'm stumped.

Please advise.

Comment: So far, the only way I have found is to use jQuery to add classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would have to do something like this

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>`
The container class you can change your class add more class