# Add Class to Custom Menu Widget ul

Tags: menus, filters, widgets

I'm trying to add a class to the built-in WordPress Custom Menu Widget. All I need to do is add a class to the ul, which has a default class of `startup-list`.

I've added the classes with jQuery but if the user isn't using JS then their navigation would break.

There has to be a WordPress way. I've tried to:

`apply_filters('wp_nav_menu', 'my-menu-name', array('menu_class' => 'my-new-class') );`

This article got me close:
[How to Modify a Widgets UL and/or LI Classes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63768/how-to-modify-a-widgets-ul-and-or-li-classes)

Comment: Have you registered the menu? Where is this code placed?

Comment: I'm adding the filter in functions.php. No, I have not registered the menu. I only created the menu on the Dashboard.